# Как вытащить svg из html

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, у меня есть скрипт, рендерящий график из Google Charts. Мне необходимо сохранить его в отчете, каким образом его вытащить? 
Через GET запрос выдает мой div в котором ничего нет.

*Мой скрипт:*

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes2);
function drawCurveTypes() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Месяц');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Количество ссылок');
    data.addRows(@{WriteLiteral(linkpad.DiagramHrefs);});
    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        colors: ['green']
        };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('href'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
function drawCurveTypes2() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Месяц');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Количество доноров');
    data.addRows(@{WriteLiteral(linkpad.DiagramDonors);});
    var options = { legend: 'none' };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('donor'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сохранить график как png. Следующий код создает картинку.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var = chart_div = document.getElementById('href')
    chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
  });
```

Comment: Тут допущены ошибки + это не совсем то что нужно.